# Rstudio Problem to render Quarto Blog, Error Permissiondenied OS Error 5

Tags: rstudio, blogs, quarto

I try to setup a Quarto Blog via Rstudio.
my system:

- R-4.3.2
- RStudio-2023.09.1-494
- Quarto 1.3.450
- Windows10 Enterprise Version 10.0.10240 Build 10240

I freshly installed R, RStudio and Quarto and changed nothing in the configurations.
When I try to setup a simple quarto blog in Rstudio (new Project -> quarto blog) and then press the render button, I get the error:

> ERROR: PermissionDenied: Zugriff verweigert (os error 5), stat 'D:\Arbeit\ooo\index_files

Thanks in advance

I run Rstudio as administrator and checked the security settings of the directory (tried other folders, partitions and even an other PC)

Searched the internet but I found no solutions.
Hopefully somebody has an idea